# Heroku's Docker app crashes on boot with more than 40 layers

Tags: docker, heroku

I have an app that I deploy to Heroku via their Docker containers. A few times my Dockerfile has gone over 40 layers. Every time that's happened, my app refuses to start and just shows a status of "crashed". (Same image starts a container up fine locally).

I believe at some point their CS suggested to get my count down below 40 layers. Sure enough, when the layer count is 40 or less, the app starts up normally. I literally change nothing besides combining a few commands to reduce the layers.

Can anyone shine some light on why Heroku has an undocumented layer limit like that?

Comment: I am not sure Heroku not documented this but why you have reached this number anyway ? :D It  is the first time to hear about this number on a dockerfile and sure you will be able to down this to less than 42 but i am wondering why in general :D

Comment: This is actually a documented behavior: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#known-issues-and-limitations

Comment: @DamienMATHIEU Thanks! Hmm, I guess I was searching for 42 and couldn't find anything, but it looks like 40 is the actual limit. It seems odd that it's just a one liner at the bottom of the docs. Having an app crash on boot without any further logs/indications can be very unexpected. Do you want to answer this with your link and I'll accept this? Hopefully this could be helpful to anyone in the future doing a Google search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This constraint is actually documented [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#known-issues-and-limitations).

The main reason for it is that under the hood, Heroku doesn't run the Docker Daemon (at least at the beginning of 2019). They download every docker layer and turn them into an LXC container, which is what all dynos on the platform are.

The ~40 layers constraint is due to internal timeouts that will have a much higher chance of being reached as there are more layers to download in order to boot the dyno.
This is an approximate constraint, as it also depends on the size of all of those layers.